# Find a string in a GitHub Pull Request

Tags: github, github-api, pull-request, octokit

I'd like to build a bot to let you know if a certain string, like `DONT_MERGE_ME` appears in a GitHub Pull Request, so I can block the commit with a failed *check* and add a helpful comment for the developer.

Let's say you had committed code like the follow, that you don't want to accidentally merge with your PR (e.g. you're hacking around).

```
const bar = 'some-hack-value'; // DONT_MERGE_ME
```

Given the PR id, I'd like to figure out if the PR still has the string `DONT_MERGE_ME` in it. However,

- the [GitHub Code Search API](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/search#search-code) has many limits, like 384KiB max file size and only searches the *default branch*
- the [GitHub Commit Search API](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/search#search-commits) only searches the *default branch*
- the [GitHub Pull Requests Search API](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/search#search-issues-and-pull-requests) only searches by title/body/comment

Given the above limitations, it looks like the only way to figure this out, for a given PR id and commit, would be to find all commits in the PR up to this commit, download the diffs, and sum them up.

Is there a simpler way to do this with the GitHub API?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The approach I would recommend is subscribe to the `pull_request` event. If `payload.action` is either `opened` or `synchronize`, [load the diff](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/overview/media-types#commits-commit-comparison-and-pull-requests) of the pull request and look for the string in all lines that have been changed.

You can preview the diff response for a pull request by adding `.diff` to any pull request URL, e.g. https://patch-diff.githubusercontent.com/raw/gr2m/sandbox/pull/194.diff

Find the lines starting with a `+` and look for your string in them

If you use the JavaScript [`octokit`](https://github.com/octokit/octokit.js/) package, you can load a pull request like this

```js
const { data: diff } = octokit.rest.pulls.get({ owner, repo, pull_number, mediaType: { format: "diff }})
```

Also check out the [TODO GitHub App](https://github.com/apps/todo), its source is Open Source, too

Answer (score 0):

I discovered (thanks for the tip, @Gregor), that there is a GitHub API for getting the pull request as a diff, if you pass certain headers.

Were we can get the delta for a repo's PR:

```js
const pullId = 14956; // NOTE: 73 files changed!
const repoFullname = 'eslint/eslint';
const url = `https://api.github.com/repos/${repoFullname}/pulls/${pullId}.diff`;
const diffStr = (await axios.get(url,requestConfig)).data;
```

Then, we can use the [`parse-diff`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/parse-diff) library to parse these, and filter out on the `add` changes, and matching content changes we want.

```js
// Search for this word
const KEYWORD = 'Requirements';
// Analyze all files
const files = parse(diffStr);
const filesWithMatchingAdds = files.map(
    file => ({
        file: file.to, 
        adds: file.chunks.map(
            chunk => chunk.changes
                // Only look for added lines
                .filter(chunk => chunk.type === 'add')
                // That match our keyword
                .filter(chunk => chunk.content.includes(KEYWORD))
        ).flat()}) // collapse into one array
// Only files with at least one match
).filter(file => file.adds.length);
```

Output looks something like

```json
[
  {
    "file": "tests/tools/internal-rules/multiline-comment-style.js",
    "adds": [
      {
        "type": "add",
        "add": true,
        "ln": 4,
        "content": "+// Requirements"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Full gist [here](https://gist.github.com/twistedpair/5d805d3f90978500a24bca67866739bc).